# Memory recomendation for LoopBack applications in Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, strongloop

We have a node application running with 256mg of memory in bluemix with the node.js runtime.

We want to monitor it in StrongLoop, so we will create a new application using the loopback boilerpante and using a local Arc we will publish our node.js application to the new loopback app using the local Arc and the new app PM.

How much do we have to increment the memory? It will be 256m needed by the app + (the memory needed by PM and monitor features)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, 512M is the recommendation:

[image]

See the doc below for more information on the LoopBack Starter:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/LoopBack/index.html

Comment: So in my case it would be 256mg (memory needed by my App) + 512mg (memory needed by StrongLoop) ? That cf push command is uploading also an App, that is why I want to clarify this.

Comment: Correct, in your case, it would be 256 + 512.